# SSRS subscription is processing but mails are not getting delivered

Tags: reporting-services, smtp, ssrs-2008-r2, subscription, reportserver

I need to schedule a SSRS report to be sent on daily basis. So, I created a data driven subscription. It's showing the status as `"Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 0 errors."`
Also in the `ReportServerDB`, there are corresponding report entries in `Subscriptions` table.
But still mails are not getting delivered. Please let me know what steps am I missing?

Comment: You probably didn't miss any steps, at least from the subscription perspective. Talk to your email admin, see if there is anything going on there.

Comment: Has any subscription email ever been delivered before?

Comment: No @WEI_DBA. I'm subscribing it for the first time.

Comment: In the Reporting Services Configuration Manager on the SSRS server, did you specify the E-mail Settings properly?

Comment: Actually, @R.Richards, I tried to ping the smtp server but it's timed out. Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: @WEI_DBA, Yes, I think so. I specified my email Id and SMTP server in the settings just for testing. Could you please tell me if we could specify our email or is there some Admin email for this purpose?

Comment: Just as long as that email account has permissions to send email from the smtp server.

Comment: Thanks @WEI_DBA for the information.

Comment: @Anshul, that could be an issue. But, pings my not be allowed to the server, or it just doesn't respond to a ping. You really need to make sure email can be sent via that server. Like, WEI_DBA mentions, permissions should be checked. A more likely culprit in this situation.

Comment: @R.Richards, thanks for the information.

Comment: Another possibility that I have encountered - the report was sent but was rejected by a mail server because the report was too large (>10M).

Comment: Actually, file size is < 100 KB. But I don't know if this is a issue because of firewall or some other thing?